# How can I get my vagrant to work without "Error, some other host already uses address"

Tags: networking, vagrant, openshift, virtualbox, ip-address

I'm a student trying to follow https://www.openshift.com/blog/using-openshift-3-on-your-local-environment

When I run vagrant up, I run into this error:

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown 'eth1'
/sbin/ifdown 'eth2'
mv -f '/tmp/vagrant-network-entry-eth1-1607533452-0' '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1'
mv -f '/tmp/vagrant-network-entry-eth2-1607533452-1' '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2'
/sbin/ifup 'eth1'
/sbin/ifup 'eth2'

Stdout from the command:

ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Error, some other host already uses address 10.2.2.2.

Stderr from the command:

I can not find a clear answer on what is going wrong and how I can fix it. Please help me get my final project started.

I'm on Mac 10.14.6, thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Check **vagrant global-status** to see if you are not running other VMs already which could have used the port